# How to run an url in views in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a PDF uploading form. When a user sends this form I want to trigger a URL in my views. I want the invoked URL address to be opened only once in the backend. The user cannot view this page. The reason I want this is that the API I call from here enables me to do another process.
How can I run an URL in my views backend?

**Note: Does using this work?**

```
 r = requests.get(url)
```

---

**views.py**

```
def upload_pdf(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=id)
        form = PdfForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_pdf = form.save(commit=False)
            new_pdf.owner = customer
            new_pdf.save()
            name = new_pdf.pdf.name.replace(".pdf", "")
            url = 'https://api..../perform/{0}'.format(name)
            return redirect('ocr', id=new_pdf.id)
    else:
        form = PdfForm()
        customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=id)

    return render(request, 'upload_pdf.html', {'form': form, 'customer': customer})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import requests

```
url = request.get/post('https://api..../perform/{0}'.format(name))
```